# Do absolutely continuous functions have bounded derivative?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am an outsider for this field of mathematical analysis. But to analyse a problem of Control Systems, which is my area of interest, I need to know this.

I learned that *absolutely continuous functions* are also *differentiable almost everywhere*. On the other hand, *Lipschitz continuity* ensures *bounded derivative* of the function a.e. I am wondering whether there is any link between the derivative being bounded and the function being absolutely continuous. Or, is there any sufficient condition to be imposed over the *absolute continuity* to ascertain that the derivative of the function will be bounded?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If a continuously differentiable function has a bounded derivative, then it is absolutely continuous. The inverse is *not* true, as shown by the function $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ on $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Hence, can it be concluded that Lipschitz continuity is the weakest condition to be imposed over absolute continuity to ensure bounded derivative of the function? Is my understanding right?

Comment: All differentiable functions with a bounded derivative are lipschitz. All lipschitz functions are absolutely continuous. All absolutely continuous functions are continuous. None of these inclusions can be inverted. So I would say that Lipschitz continuity is a *stronger* condition, because it works on *more* functions than bounded derivatives. It is *easier* to chech bounded derivatives.

Answer (score 0):

As @5xum mentioned, an absolutely continuous function may not have a bounded derivative.

But there is a weaker result which is true: The derivative of every Lipschitz continuous function(which is a condition slightly better than the absolutely continuity) is essentially bounded(i.e. bounded a.e.).

A proof for the weaker result could be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1561762/lipschitz-continuity-is-equivalent-to-absolute-continuity-with-bounded-derivativ). And one should know that, even though in the link they write $|f^\prime(x)|$ without a.e., it actually means $|f^\prime(x)|$ for a.e. $x$.